# Regarding program startup in the standard

Tags: c, language-lawyer

I have a couple of questions regarding § 5.1.2.2.2 in the standard.

> 1. The function called at program startup is named **main**. The implementation declares no prototype for this function. It shall be
>      defined with a return type of **int** and with no parameters:
>
>    `int main(void) { /* ... */ }`
>
>    or with two parameters (referred to here as
>      **argc** and **argv**, though any names may be used, as they are local to the
>      function in which they are declared):
>
>    `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }`
>
>    or equivalent;<sup>10)</sup> or in some other
>      implementation-defined manner.

What does "some other implementation-defined manner" refer to? Does it refer to footnote 10, which states:

> Thus, **int** can be replaced by a typedef name defined as **int**, or
>   the type of **argv** can be written as **char ** argv**, and so on.

...or the actual definition of main? If so, does this mean that given a certain implementation, the compiler can say `main` should be defined however it wants (this runs contrary to what I've read on the internet saying it must be `int main`. For example, in § 5.1.2.2.3 it states:

> 1. If the return type of the **main** function is a type compatible with **int**, a return from the initial call to the **main** function is equivalent
>      to calling the **exit** function with the value returned by the **main**
>      function as its argument;<sup>11)</sup> reaching the **}** that terminates the **main**
>      function returns a value of 0. If the return type is not compatible
>      with **int**, the termination status returned to the host environment is
>      unspecified.

...which seems to leave a lot of leeway to the implementation.

> — The parameters **argc** and **argv** and the strings pointed to by
>   the **argv** array shall be modifiable by the program, and retain
>   their last-stored values between program startup and program
>   termination.

What does "retain their last-stored values mean"? Does this mean functions like [`getopt`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt) violate the standard because they permute argv?

Answer (score 2):

> What does "some other implementation-defined manner" refer to?

The C standard provides only two signatures for `main`:

```
int main(void) { /* ... */ }
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
```

But some implementations also allow some different signatures.

On Mac OS:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[], char* envp[], char* apple[]);
```

On Windows:

```
int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[], wchar_t* envp[]);
```

POSIX supports

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
```

Answer (score 1):

No; it means that [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wd819wh%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) can document:

```
void main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
```

as a valid signature for `main()` on their system and it is valid as a result of the 'or in some other implementation-defined manner'.

The footnote means you can use:

```
typedef int num;

num main(num argc, char **argv)
```

and it remains valid.

See also [What should `main()` return in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c/18721336#18721336).

The 'last modified values' bit means that when `getopt()` permutes the values in `argv`, the permutations it sets stay in effect until overridden by something else changing the values in `argv`.